# Double Notifications in Flutter firebase messaging

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Recently I upgraded to firebase_messaging: ^10.0.0 When app is in not running and if notification comes it is displaying twice. I modified the notification data in code after receiving and displayed it. Even then I can see the modified and non modified notifications. I don't know where that notification is triggering. But when app is running it is displaying notification once only(works fine). Here goes my code

```
/*main.dart*/
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  //await Firebase.initializeApp();

  // await HomePageState.handleMessage(message);
  String title="${message.notification!.title}";
  String body="${message.notification!.body}";

  _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(0, title, body, platformChannelSpecifics, payload: jsonEncode(message.data));

  AppDatabase database= await $FloorAppDatabase.databaseBuilder(Constants.dataBaseName).addMigrations([migration1to2]).build();
  if(!title.toLowerCase().contains("cancelled")){
    var date=DateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm aa").format(DateTime.now());
    NotificationModel notification=NotificationModel(title: title,message: body,read: 0,date: date);
    await database.notificationDao.insertNotification(notification);
  }

  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}
Future<void> main() async {
  //this line make sure all the required widgets are loaded before main application starts
  //SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({});
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  var initializationSettingsAndroid = new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_notification');
  var initializationSettingsIOS = new IOSInitializationSettings(onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification);
  //var initializationSettings = new InitializationSettings(initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
  var initializationSettings = new InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid,iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
  _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,onSelectNotification: onSelectingNotification);

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);


  //Initializing repository and carrying forward to avoid multiple instances of database
  Repository _repository = Repository();

  // runApp(BlocProvider(
  //   create: (_) => ThemeBloc()..add(ThemeLoadStarted()),
  //   child: MyApp(
  //     repository: _repository,
  //   ),
  // ));
  SentryOptions options=SentryOptions(dsn: APIs.sentryAPI);
  final SentryClient _sentry = SentryClient(options);

  Future<void> _reportErrorToSentry(dynamic error, dynamic stackTrace) async {
    // Print the exception to the console.
    print('Caught error: $error');
   await  _sentry.captureException(
      error,
      stackTrace: stackTrace,
    );
  }

  runZonedGuarded(() async{
    // runApp(BlocProvider(
    //   create: (_) => ThemeBloc()..add(ThemeLoadStarted()),
    //   child: MyApp(
    //     repository: _repository,
    //   ),
    // ));

    await SentryFlutter.init(
          (options) => options.dsn = APIs.sentryAPI,
      appRunner: () => runApp(BlocProvider(
        create: (_) => ThemeBloc()..add(ThemeLoadStarted()),
        child: MyApp(
          repository: _repository,
        ),
      )),
    );
  }, (error, stackTrace) {
    print('runZonedGuarded: Caught error in my root zone.');
    FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stackTrace);
    _reportErrorToSentry(error,stackTrace);
  });

}
```

Application.kt

```
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
import io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService


class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry) {
        //FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry)
        FlutterLocalNotificationPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry)
        SqflitePluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry)
    }
}
```

FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.kt which I commented out in application.kt

```
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin
class FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant {
    companion object {
        fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry) {
            if (alreadyRegisteredWith(registry)) {
                return
            }
            FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"))
        }

        fun alreadyRegisteredWith(registry: PluginRegistry): Boolean {
            val key = FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant::class.java.name
            if (registry.hasPlugin(key)) {
                return true
            }
            registry.registrarFor(key)
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="**.***.***tomer">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<!--    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />-->
<!--    android:label="@string/app_label"-->
    <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:label="Zuzu"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.network-policy"
            android:resource="@xml/network_security_config"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            tools:targetApi="n">

            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBqZ4aa************GMzHpofWKeEU"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="Zuzu" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_notification"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/notification"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

[image]
This issue is in android only that too when app is not running. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you find a solution ? i have the same problem

Comment: @Fatimaayaa I removed "notification":{} in payload. Added title and body in data itself. This fixed the bug. But notifications gets delayed for sometime when app is not running.

Answer (score 6):

It appears you're sending a "notification" message from Firebase Messaging when you should be sending a "data" message.

Here is the difference between a notification message and a data message:

> **Notification message**
>
> FCM automatically displays the message to end-user devices on behalf
> of the client app.
>
> **Data message**
>
> Client app is responsible for processing data messages.
>
> [About FCM Messages | Firebase (#Message types)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)

That explains why you get the unmodified version of the notification (this is from the automatic display of the notification message) and the modified version of the notification (this is from your own code where you handle the notification).

**Solution:**

You need to send a data message from your backend.
So if you had this before as your notification payload:

```js
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification":{
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "body" : "great match!",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
}
```

you should change it to:

```js
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "data":{
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "body" : "great match!",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how can i trigger onMessageOpenedApp when notification type is data

Comment: You can't do that since you will be one to handle displaying the notification when the notification type is `data`. So it should be included in your implementation.

Comment: Will it show the notification when the app is in killed state?

Comment: No, it won't. Your app has to be open to handle `data` messages.