# Google Firebase FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen calling multple times in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Google FCM to get notification from back end there are some situation where i am getting called   `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen` multiple times but after doing some research i have found that there is an issue

> [bug](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1669)

after searching for a solution i had no option only option was to do this type of work around

```
  if ((DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch - _lastOnResumeCall) >
                  7000000 &&
              _lastUniqId != message.data['uniqueId'].toString()) {
       _lastUniqId = message.data['uniqueId'].toString();
            _lastOnResumeCall = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch;
      //showing local notification if condition is true

}
```

but the issue is still remains is there any solution or work around that can be implemented?

[image: Flutter doctor Result]

[image: Firebase version that currently using]

**This is are the version that i am using currently**

**Update**

```
    // ignore_for_file: avoid_print

import 'dart:io';

import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:project/api/login_request.dart';
import 'package:project/controller/dashboard.dart';
// import 'package:project/models/remote_message.dart';
import 'package:project/utils/global.dart';
import 'package:project/utils/routes.dart';

class FCMProvider {
  static bool gotNewNotification = false;

  DashBoardController conttroller = Get.put(DashBoardController());
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  String? token;
  String? notificationId;
  GlobalFunctions gf = GlobalFunctions();
  String accessToken = "";
  String userRoll = "0";
  String _lastUniqId = "";
  int counte = 0;
  int _lastOnResumeCall = 0;
  int _lastOnResumeCall2 = 0;
  String _lastIdFromshowMessage = "";
  int smearphone = 0;
  UserAPIRepository userAPIRepository = UserAPIRepository();

  stop() {
    messaging.unsubscribeFromTopic("all");
  }

  start() {
    if (accessToken.length > 1) messaging.subscribeToTopic("all");
  }

  initialize() async {
    accessToken = await gf.getToken();
    userRoll = await gf.getRoleId();

    NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );

    token = await messaging.getToken();

    await userAPIRepository.setFirebaseToken(token);
    messaging.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: Platform.isAndroid,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );

    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(
      (RemoteMessage message) async {
        if (message.notification != null) {
          // // conttroller.changeTabIndex(2);
          // // (DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch - _lastOnResumeCall) >10000000 &&
          // if (_lastUniqId.toString() != message.data['uniqueId'].toString()) {

          // }
          if (smearphone != 0) {
            return;
          }
          smearphone = 1;
          Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
            smearphone = 0;
          });
          String oldunqi = _lastUniqId;
          _lastUniqId = message.data['uniqueId'].toString();

          showNotification(
            "Last Unqie Id " + oldunqi.toString(),
            "Recived Unqiue Id" + _lastUniqId.toString(),
            _lastUniqId.toString(),
          );
        }
      },
    );

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
      if (accessToken.length > 1) {
        if (message.data.containsKey("notificationType")) {
          if (message.data["notificationType"] == "Message") {
            if (userRoll == "5") {
              conttroller.changeTabIndex(2);
            } else {
              conttroller.changeTabIndex(1);
            }
          } else {
            conttroller.changeTabIndex(0);
          }
        }
        // showNotification(message.notification!.title.toString(),
        //     message.notification!.body.toString());
        FCMProvider.gotNewNotification = true;
        Get.toNamed(Routes.splash);
      }
    });

    start();
  }

  showNotification(String title, String message, id, {int type = 0}) {
    // Get.dialog(
    //   AlertDialog(
    //     title: Text(title),
    //     content: Text(message),
    //     actions: <Widget>[
    //       FlatButton(
    //         child: Text("Ok"),
    //         onPressed: () {
    //           Get.back();
    //         },
    //       )
    //     ],
    //   ),
    // );
    Get.showSnackbar(GetSnackBar(
      borderRadius: 10,
      maxWidth: 250,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
      messageText: Text(
        "Varibel checking" +
            (_lastIdFromshowMessage.toString() != id.toString()).toString() +
            " New id" +
            id.toString() +
            " Last Id" +
            _lastIdFromshowMessage.toString(),
        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
    ));
    if (_lastIdFromshowMessage.toString() != id.toString()) {
      _lastIdFromshowMessage = id.toString();
      Get.snackbar(
        title,
        message,
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
        dismissDirection: DismissDirection.horizontal,
        boxShadows: const [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.white,
            offset: Offset(0, 0),
          ),
        ],
        colorText: Colors.black, //kGreen,
      );
    }
  }
}

Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print(message.data);
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}
```

This is pushnotification class

```
import 'package:portal_del_familiar/controller/bindings/dashboardbind.dart';

import 'package:portal_del_familiar/ui/my_app.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await GetStorage.init();
  DashboardBinding().dependencies();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

**Main.dart**

As you can see i am checking another solution also i will update if there is any changes. and i have checked the variables are not updating in condition since the messages are reeving concurrently really appreciate if you can give a way to update the variable before next call is come.

Answer (score 3):

Okay now i know this is bit lame but i was able to fix the issue. The reason was who ever done code was calling Firebase Messaging init function in 3 places one in Splash screen second  login success and in the end when login out so every time it was creating a instance so that way first it's create a instance in splash then in login (that's make 2) then when user logged out and login it's create another instance so every time it's increase one listener so this was the reason so for my solution i have placed init in the main() and removed from every other place and this fixed the issue. @Uni Gandhi Thank you very much for you help on that day.

Comment: How to avoid my firebase instance has been initialized multiple time?

Comment: my issue was i was calling  ` await Firebase.initializeApp();` in multiple places if you can provide the code i can look into to it

Answer (score 0):

Not happening in my case. I am getting only 1 notification message.

You could try implementing another workaround using a simple integer and displaying the message based on odd/even values.

If you could share your Firebase initialization and OnMessage code then a better solution can be provided.

Comment: as for the request i have updated the code with my push notification and main class init

Comment: The solution in top also didn't work this one  ` if (smearphone != 0) {
            return;
          }
          smearphone = 1;
          Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
            smearphone = 0;
          });
        

          showNotification(
            "Last Unqie Id " + oldunqi.toString(),
            "Recived Unqiue Id" + _lastUniqId.toString(),
            _lastUniqId.toString(),
          );`

Comment: Two things. 1st, why are you using 2 tokens? i.e token and accessToken. 2nd, is your backend logic based on subscription? If not then try commenting the subscription code and try once again.

Also, try updating the plugins for Firebase Core and Messaging to the latest ones on pub.dev

Comment: Nope i am pure base on firebase token so you mean i don't need those subscriptions?

Comment: I mean the topic subscriptions where you have subscribed to 'all'. Try commenting that once and also by updating plugins.

Comment: Okay ill try that thank you for the help. I am in flutter 2.8 that's why i didn't update it ill try it. Again thank you very much i have no words

Comment: And another thing this is happening only in my real device in Emulator nothing happens as i can can it be i have use my real device to login udong multiple users can it be a reason?

Comment: Hi i have removed subscriptions. i don't know the reason this double notification issue is only happening in my device i can't figure out why i have check in another 2 devices they don't receive this double notifications only my devices get it's from the beginning i have used my device for testing so i have logged in with multiple account suspects that's the reason still i can't figure out why

Comment: Did you try uninstall - reinstall process? It might help, as this issue is only occurring in one particular device.

Comment: Yes now i was abel to fix the issue like this clearing the catch but if user logout and login again this happens again can this be a reason? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67820474/double-notifications-in-flutter-firebase-messaging